# MRefBuilder invalid character exception on SandCastle

Tags: .net, sandcastle

I'm trying to use the Sandcastle Help File Builder to generate a help file for my assembly.
When I run the build I get the following error:

```
 MrefBuilder (v2.4.10520.1)
  Copyright c Microsoft 2006
  Info: Loaded 1 assemblies for reflection and 15 dependency assemblies.

  Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character.
     at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Char* pDst, Boolean entitize)
     at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteAttributeTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
     at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
     at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
     at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
     at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String localName, String value)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.ManagedReflectionWriter.WriteTypeElements(TypeNode type)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.ManagedReflectionWriter.WriteType(TypeNode type)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.ManagedReflectionWriter.VisitType(TypeNode type)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.Reflection.ApiVisitor.VisitTypes(TypeNodeList types)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.Reflection.ApiVisitor.VisitNamespace(Namespace space)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.ManagedReflectionWriter.VisitNamespace(Namespace space)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.Reflection.ApiVisitor.VisitNamespaces(NamespaceList spaces)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.ManagedReflectionWriter.VisitNamespaces(NamespaceList spaces)
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.Reflection.ApiVisitor.VisitApis()
     at Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.MRefBuilder.Main(String[] args)
```

I also get this error when running from the command line.

I've used a hex editor to examine the Documentation.xml that VS outputs, and there is not a character 0x02 in the file.

Does anyone have any clue or advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be related to a DLL that I had to use to connect to SAP.  ERP Connect.  Once I eliminated that namespace, everything went well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you eliminated that namespace? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I created a class called "NamespaceDoc.cs"

I put that in my problem namespace, and then set the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGenerated()] attribute on the class.

This forces it to ignore all classes in this namespace